# Using Kinect V2 in Matlab Image Acquisition Tool

Tags: matlab, kinect

I want to use the new Kinect v2 sensor in Matlab, but the `info = imaqhwinfo` doesn't show me `Kinect` among `InstalledAdaptors`. I've already used Kinect v2 as webcam in Skype following the instructions http://codingbytodesign.net/2014/07/20/kinectcamv2-for-kinect-v2/#comment-286432 and it works properly, but in "Control Panel->Device Manager" Kinect doesn't appear as a "Imaging Device".

Does anyone known how to configure Kinect as a Imaging Device (in order to use it as a classical webcam)?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: I read from <http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/answers/146494-matlab-support-for-microsoft-kinect-for-windows-v2> that Matlab doesn't support all the new Kinect functionalities yet, but if I use it like a webcam my problem seems to be resolved. Is correct? Thanks!

Comment: I've finally found a program, ManyCam ([http://manycam.com/]), that allows you to use Kinect as a webcam in many applications (including Matlab `imaqtool`). But for my purposes the stream visualized is too slow... does anyone know a different method to solve my problem? Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

The Kinect is not supported yet. I have had to do the following:-

Application - Develop an independent application (cpp in my case) to save the depth, skeleton and rgb image.

Matlab - I'be developed an application that can read in all the inputs and display to the user.

Let us know if you're interested in seeing the code. I'll release it.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, I'm very interested in your code

Comment: I will generate a Stackoverflow Post detailing the "how-to" guide.

Comment: Take a look at the following question/answer 25700993

Comment: I look at your answer, I implemented the RGB part but I could only see one frame. For my purpose, I need the RGB stream from the Kinect (saved as an .avi file for example) in order to pass it to my Matlab application. Thanks anyway for your answer!

Comment: If you pose it as a question, I'll provide an answer. So, create a new Stack post!

Comment: I've posted another question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25886144/save-rgb-stream-from-kinect-v2